# Storing .png images in an ios app?

Tags: iphone, ios

Im creating an iphone game that will use more than 1200 .png image files, and all the images combined together come up to the size 11mb, i was wondering whats the best way to store them, i was going to use the s3 storage by amazon, but I would love them to be apart of the app in the resources folder, so users can play offline aswell. So i wanted get any opinions in what is the best way to store images in terms of caching and optimizating .png files in use with IOS Apps. thanks

Comment: iOS and Xcode are quite good at optimizing PNG files to their maximum efficiency.  Perhaps you need to take a different approach.

Comment: Do you want to save them while running or while developing to the resources?

Comment: no im going using them through out the app, im not saving images, thier just images of animals that i have chose? the user deosnt upload any photos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drag them into xcode. 11 MB is not much, apple has raised their download limit over 3G/Edge.

Once you have them inside your project, you just call them like

```
UIImage *myImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
```

It doesn't get simpler.

If you don't put the files inside your project and have to download them, you download these into your Documents folder. You can put what ever you want in that directory, as it is only for your project and no other project has access to it

Comment: If he's dealing with 1200 images, maybe he should use `imageWithContentsOfFile` instead of `imageNamed`. The latter's caching logic is subject of some debate. Perhaps not an issue if the images are so small (and if the likelihood is that a very small subset of the images will be used during a session), but although it's convenient, I'd be wary of using `imageNamed`.

Comment: I agree, totally, without a doubt

Answer (score 1):

11MB isn't much these days, your app can be upto 50MB and still be available to download over cellular networks so the best solution is;

a) Don't worry about it. Put them in your resources folder.

If you are going to have lots more images, then the easiest solution is to simply download them when the app has a network connection. You can store them in the Documents folder and mark them as do not backup so that they aren't synchronised with iCloud. You could also store them in the Caches folder, but that makes them much more liable to vanish at any moment so you would need to have a slightly more complex mechanism to recognise they are no longer on disk and to pull them in afresh.